# In Tfs 2008 to 2010 upgrade how to point tfs database of another server in the configure wizard?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Tfs 2008 to be upgraded to TFS 2010, how do i point the database which is in another server in different domain? Otherwise is it possible to install as fresh and then move the database from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010? is there a option to directly move the database from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you back up the databases, restore them on the new server and use the configuration wizard to upgrade them.

There's a number of blog posts with good walkthroughs.

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/upgrading-team-foundation-server-2008-to-2010/